# Scrape text file with Python

Tags: python, extract, text-parsing

I have multiple text files with text in exact format **named st.txt**

```
Combination :3   Tuple Number:3
Request Type:ADD
Firewall Type:JP
Firewall Policy Name :STI-CEP31

Rule Type: ALLOW

Requested Values:

Policy Name Suffix: 

Source IP: GRN

Source Groups:
10.151.2.0/24
10.151.1.0/24

Destination IP: Untrusted 
Destination Group:
169.176.39.0/24
169.176.38.0/24

Application(s):
Application Group:

Service Mode:Use Protocol/Ports
Service Group:

Protocol/Ports:

TCP      |       21099


Combination :5   Tuple Number:16
Request Type:ADD
Firewall Type:JP
Firewall Policy Name :STI-CEP31

Rule Type: ALLOW

Requested Values:

Policy Name Suffix: 

Source IP: GRN

Source Groups:
10.151.2.0/24
10.151.1.0/24


Destination IP: Untrusted 
Destination Group:
169.176.39.0/24
169.176.38.0/24
154.154.55.221
154.25.55.662
148.55.465.653

Application(s):
Application Group:

Service Mode:Use Protocol/Ports
Service Group:

Protocol/Ports:

TCP      |       219


Combination :100   Tuple Number:100
Request Type:ADD
Firewall Type:JP
Firewall Policy Name :STI-CEP31

Rule Type: ALLOW

Requested Values:

Policy Name Suffix: 

Source IP: GRN

Source Groups:
10.151.2.0/24
10.151.1.0/24

Destination IP: Untrusted 
Destination Group:
169.176.38.0/24
154.154.55.222
154.25.55.61
148.55.465.651

Application(s):
Application Group:

Service Mode:Use Protocol/Ports
Service Group:

Protocol/Ports:

TCP      |       210
```

I am trying to create a python code which will consider each line starting with Combination as one block, For eg: There are three blocks in this text file (One starting with Combination :3, One starting with Combination: 5 and one starting with Combination : 100). Search through each block for the IP "169.176.39.0/24", If there is entry found (For eg: in block starting with 3 and 5 there is entry for 169.176.39.0/24 in the Destination Group section), then print the Source Groups IP's, Destination Group: IP's and Ports.

So for example from this file, the **output should look like**

```
Combination :3   Tuple Number:3 # Source Groups: 10.151.2.0/24 10.151.1.0/24 # Destination Group: 169.176.39.0/24 169.176.38.0/24 # Ports # 21099

Combination :5   Tuple Number:16 # Source Groups: 10.151.2.0/24 10.151.1.0/24 # Destination Group: 169.176.39.0/24 169.176.38.0/24 154.154.55.221 154.25.55.662 148.55.465.653 # Ports # 219
```

Code which I tried just prints Destination Group IP's but I am unable to add Combination to the list.

**Code I tried to Pull Destination Group IP's**

```
    data = f.read()

# Split data into blocks
blocks = data.split('\n\n')

# Extract desired information from each block
for block in blocks:

    if "169.176.39.0/24" in block:
        lines = block.split('\n\n')
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            if "Destination Group:" in line:
                start = i + 1
                break
        result = " ".join(lines[start:]).strip()
        print(lines[0], result)
```

**Code I tried to pull Combination number and Tuple number from the file**

```
import os

directory = os.curdir
search_string = "169.176.39.0/24"

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    filepath = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
        with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
            header = ''
            for line in file:
                if line.startswith("Combination"):
                    header = line.strip()
                elif search_string in line:
                    o1 = header
                    print(f"{filename}#{o1}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text file doesn't seem to be formatted in such a way that you can split it into meaningful block every "\n\n".

`Source Groups`, `Destination Group`, `Protocol/Ports` are all attributes whose values span multiple lines. I assume every line below the attribute name is a value unless it's empty or contains a colon, suggesting it's another single-line key:value pair (which is simply ignored).

I assume a block starts/ends at a line starting with `Combination` or the end of the file.

In the code below I create a list of dictionaries containing all the blocks. After that, I create another dictionary with only the blocks containing a specific IP address. Finally, the blocks are formatted and printed.

```py
filename = r"C:\Users\Desktop\Todd Bonzalez\st.txt"

blocks = []
attributes = ("Source Groups", "Destination Group", "Protocol/Ports")

with open(filename) as f:
    block = {}
    in_section = None
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            # Stop consuming values for multi-line attributes if the line 
            # contains a colon. It's assumed to be another single-line 
            # attribute:value pair.
            if ":" in line:
                in_section = None
            
            # The end of a block starts/ends at a line starting with 
            # "Combination" or the end of the file
            if line.startswith("Combination"):
                if block:
                    blocks.append(block)
                    block = {}
                
                block["block"] = line
                
            # Consume the line since we're in a multi-line attribute section
            elif in_section:
                values = block.setdefault(in_section, [])
                
                # We only want the port
                if in_section == "Protocol/Ports":
                    line = line.split("|", maxsplit=2)[1].strip()
                
                values.append(line)
                
            # Check if the line is the start of a multi-line attribute
            else:
                for attribute in attributes:
                    if line.startswith(attribute):
                        in_section = attribute
                        break

# The end of a block starts/ends at a line starting with 
# "Combination" or the end of the file
if block:
    blocks.append(block)

# Create a new list of blocks if it contains a particular IP address
blocks_with_certain_ip = []
for block in blocks:
    search_string = "169.176.39.0/24"
    if search_string in block["Source Groups"] or search_string in block["Destination Group"]:
        blocks_with_certain_ip.append(block)

# Format and print the blocks as desired
for block in blocks_with_certain_ip:
    string = (f'{block["block"]} '
              f'# Source Groups: {" ".join(block["Source Groups"])} '
              f'# Destination Group: {" ".join(block["Destination Group"])} '
              f'# Ports # {" ".join(block["Protocol/Ports"])}')
    print(string)
```

Output:

```
Combination :3   Tuple Number:3 # Source Groups: 10.151.2.0/24 10.151.1.0/24 # Destination Group: 169.176.39.0/24 169.176.38.0/24 # Ports # 21099
Combination :5   Tuple Number:16 # Source Groups: 10.151.2.0/24 10.151.1.0/24 # Destination Group: 169.176.39.0/24 169.176.38.0/24 154.154.55.221 154.25.55.662 148.55.465.653 # Ports # 219
```

Comment: Thanks, Gordon. This works perfectly as expected. Appreciate your response for this question and your time

Comment: Hey @GordonAitchJay 
I modified the ask of the question, seems like I am looking for more specific details from the text provide its not a big change, since you already know the answer and all the attributes and they worked as you mentioned. Please if you can invest some time to get the new answer, that would be great
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75925212/scrape-text-file-with-python-and-save-to-new-text-file-as-values

Comment: No worries. I'll answer your new question tomorrow.

Comment: Appreciate that

Comment: Hey @GordonAitchJay
I added further details to this link, this might give better clarity on the code 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75933674/modify-python-code-to-include-user-input-search-feature